# Set a repeating value to 0 while leaving the first value alone

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am currently writing a report and noticed that I am getting repeated values. The issue is not that the values are repeating but that I am getting values that should be 0 after the first initial value.

For example:

My report is displaying the estimated shipping cost which might be `$700` and since the order was broken up into 3 shipments, the report prints  `$700` 3 times. This is not true because the estimated shipping should only be calculated one time.

***I am using iReport***

**My question is:** *How do I keep the first repeating value the same but every value after it set to '0' ?*

Here is an image to better explain.
[image]

---

***This is my SQL***

```
SELECT
 CUSTOMER."NAME" AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
 SO."NUM" AS SO_NUM,
 COMPANY."NAME" AS COMPANY_NAME,
 SHIPCARTON."FREIGHTAMOUNT" AS SHIPCARTON_FREIGHTAMOUNT,
 SHIP."SOID" AS SHIP_SOID,
 SOITEM."UNITPRICE" AS SOITEM_UNITPRICE,
 PRODUCT."PARTID" AS PRODUCT_PARTID,
 SHIP."DATESHIPPED" AS SHIP_DATESHIPPED
FROM
 "CUSTOMER" CUSTOMER INNER JOIN "SO" SO ON CUSTOMER."ID" = SO."CUSTOMERID"
 INNER JOIN "SHIP" SHIP ON SO."ID" = SHIP."SOID"
 INNER JOIN "SOITEM" SOITEM ON SO."ID" = SOITEM."SOID"
 INNER JOIN "PRODUCT" PRODUCT ON SOITEM."PRODUCTID" = PRODUCT."ID"
 INNER JOIN "SHIPCARTON" SHIPCARTON ON SHIP."ID" = SHIPCARTON."SHIPID",
 "COMPANY" COMPANY
WHERE
 PRODUCT."PARTID" = 947
 AND SHIP."DATESHIPPED" BETWEEN $P{From} AND $P{To}
 AND SHIPCARTON."FREIGHTAMOUNT" != 0
ORDER BY
2
```

**UPDATE**

Now my variable  `shipPriceDif` is not able to calculate my new variable `estimatedShipPrice`. Even after setting the variable to the group.

Here is a picture to explain further-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to include your sql, you can easily remove the duplicated value (not display anything), but maybe should consider to design your report differently es. grouping on shipment and then showing other cost under

Comment: @PetterFriberg is there no way to maybe set it to a counter variable and then make it to where if the counter is greater then 1 set those variables to "0"?

Comment: Sure but it's better to group need to see your database structure to understand how.

Comment: I posted my SQL. thank you

Comment: Ok what is duplicating your records (the SHIPCARTON)?

Comment: SOITEM."UNITPRICE" AS SOITEM_UNITPRICE is repeating but I want the first time it repeats to say the number and the second time (after ordering) to be set to 0

Comment: add SOITEM."SOID" in the query as a field, then group in report on this, the report will also become more beautiful, in group header you put the current data and in detail band only data that changes...

Comment: Im do not know how to do that. I am still learning.

Comment: It's easy time to start trying. ; )

Comment: Agreed :3 thank you for your help - I still dont know how to fix my problem but maybe I can figure it out

Comment: You should re-design report ; ), not solve this problem... using group to display shipping cost 1 time and then the other costs under

Comment: Well until I can focus and learn grouping is there now way to satisfy this report with any sort of fix?

Comment: You just wan't to display 0....

Comment: Yeah but I want to set just the repeating values to 0 not the intial one. That's my issue

Comment: Launching eclipse, stand by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your sql `SOITEM."SOID"` (we check if this is duplicated), you get a field

```xml
<field name="SOID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

Create a **group** on the `SOID`

```xml
<group name="SOID">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{SOID}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

Then create a **variable** that reset's with the group counting the occurrence of `SOID`

```xml
<variable name="SOID_Count" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="SOID" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{SOID}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

The sequence in the jrxml of this code will be

```xml
<field name="SOID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<variable name="SOID_Count" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="SOID" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{SOID}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<group name="SOID">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{SOID}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

This variable can now be used to evaluate if you have duplicated SOID, it will be **>1** when duplicated `SOID`

**Example** of `textField` that display 0 if duplicated `SOID`

```xml
<textField pattern="###0">
    <reportElement x="143" y="0" width="105" height="20" uuid="a0e2ae10-906e-4d0f-aebd-30fc0c694aca">
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SOID_Count}<=1?$F{SOITEM_UNITPRICE}:0]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The day you like to improve your report, just add a `groupHeader` band in your group and then put the textField's in this band

Comment: I did this Petter and what do i do after i make the SOID_Count variable?

Comment: I understand now. I apologize it took me a minute. Now my issue is that it is replacing the numbers with a Zero but it's still doing the math as if the numbers are still there.

Comment: What expression do you have doing math?, change the expression... : ), you have also a nice group... however edit your post so I can see the expression you are having troble with

Comment: At least we solve the initial problem and now we show 0 ; )

Comment: @Ashton Can't understand which column is which, to help my make a short example on what is happening now (column names, values),  and what you wish would happen (what should the values be)

Comment: Petter i added a picture better explaining. It seems that the counter is not changing the first value after 700 but the ones after it are fine. How can i solve this :/? thanks!

Comment: Actually this question is answered- I will start a new question!

Comment: Petter here is a link to my new question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001443/ireport-counter-equation-is-off-by-1