# How to combine two already functioning reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have done some research on subreports and have even built report that use several subreports.

I am having an issue combining 2 already made reports so that they both run and print out (***one on first page***, ***one on second page***).

**How can I do this?
Do I have to include every single item in those reports SQL statements or just the parameters that cause for input?**

I am using iReport to build my custom jasper reports,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

**1. Combine report creating a main report and include you reports in this as subreport's**. You need to set margin to 0, `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` and for example use the `summary` band to generate new page for report2 setting `isSummaryNewPage="true"`. You do not need to change any queries, since you simple pass the report connection to your reports (subreports).

Example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="612" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isSummaryNewPage="true" uuid="9ac8b394-36b0-409a-8a94-b8147d9c2d20">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\jdd\\projects\\StackTrace\\jasper\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="20">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="612" height="20" uuid="e98a3620-58d6-47c1-8c93-6ca3d749b31b"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="20">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="612" height="20" uuid="bc0c1758-9ce9-4f6d-a01c-2c77f59ae1fa"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**2. Concatenate the report's during exporting**

Example (pdf export is similar with other types of export)

```java
Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<JasperPrint> jasperPrintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report1, paramMap);
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint1);
JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report2, paramMap);
jasperPrintList.add(jasperPrint2);

JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrintList)); //Set as export input my list with JasperPrint s
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("output.pdf")); //or any other out stream
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Petter i feel i have it all correct but when ever i try and display it all it simply keeps running. I get no errors but it wont run both of them. Is this because i have them aboth placed in the detail banner?

Comment: Yes don't put them in detail band, if you do you need to pass an EmptyDatasource(1) and you have no controll on page break for report 2

Comment: Check how I used the the title band and summary band as example setting the whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" and make sure you pass the report connection

Comment: Wonderful! Placing one in the Title band and one in the Summery band worked! Thank you Petter!

Answer (score 1):

There is now a third way to concatenate them, especially if the reports have **different page size and/or orientation.**

Instead of running them as subreports inside a master report, you can run them as parts inside a book report.

Please check the /demo/samples/book sample inside the [JR Lib project distro](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases) package and you can see how 3 reports with different layouts are run together to produce a single file output.

Also, the [/demo/samples/tableofcontents sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/tableofcontents/) relies on this new type of report template, which we call book and is made of parts instead of bands.